# Cannot Find Voice

Tags: lilypond

My code compiles, but with errors; It says:

```
warning: cannot find Voice `chorus'
chorusLyrics = \new Lyrics 
                           \lyricsto "chorus" {
```

So I've minimized the entire code to just this:

```
\version "2.19.44"
\language "english"

\header {
    title = "debug"
}

signature = {
    \time 4/4  
    \key c \minor
    \autoBeamOff
}

chorus = \new Voice = "chorus" \relative c'' {
    \signature
    << { g f e f } \\ {e b e c } >> 
}

chorusLyrics = \new Lyrics \lyricsto "chorus" {
  This is de- bug
}

\score {
        <<
      \new Staff {  \chorus }
      \chorusLyrics
        >>
}
```

The lilypond version is correct.

The output does not display the lyrics; I've spent hours trying to figure this out.  The docs say you can use multiple voices this way.  What am I doing wrong?

Here is a quote from the Learning.pdf document:

```
Here’s how we split the chords above into two voices and add both the
passing note and a slur: \key g \major % Voice "1" Voice "2" << { g4
fis8( g) a4 g } \\ { d4 d d d } >>
```

However, if I remove the `\\` from between the curly brackets, everything compiles without a single problem - no errors at all.

Answer (score 0):

There are two problems in your example.
First, you are trying to associate a lyric to a **polyphonic** passage and this is not possible as far as I know.
Second, the structure is not correct, see an example below which compiles fine.

```
\version "2.19.44"
\language "english"

\header {
  title = "debug"
}

signature = {
  \time 4/4
  \key c \minor
  \autoBeamOff
}

upper = \relative c'' {
  \signature
  g4 f e f
}

lower = \relative c' {
  \signature
  e4 b e c
}


chorusLyrics = \lyricmode {
  This is de- bug
}

\score {
  <<
    \new Staff <<
    \new Voice = "chorus" { \voiceOne \upper }
    \new Voice { \voiceTwo \lower }
    >>
  \new Lyrics \lyricsto "chorus" { \chorusLyrics }
  >>
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the template; yes, I know I can do it with two voices that way; but I was wanting to get the sample to work from the docs.  My example has no issues whatsoever if I remove the `\\` from between the curlies.